# Macbook Pro Retina 13" Touchpad not responsive

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, trackpad

I've got a Macbook Pro Retina 13" with Mavericks installed and the Touchpad is not responsive and sometimes I have to click up to ten times before it will recognize my click.
I removed the **tap-to-click** and I really have to press the touchpad.

I've used the exact same setup on my previous Macbook Pro (non retina) without issues.

Is there something I can reset myself before contacting Apple? I've bought this Macbook
 just a bit over 3 months ago - so the Apple Care you get by default is no longer valid.

As my search online I've found a fix, but this fix is not written for my software it claims on installation: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1704?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm never really into answering my own posts but after calling AppleCare (even though I had no longer valid AppleCare I still tried it) it turns out to be a hardware issue.
My macbook is going away for repair on next monday and it will take up to 5 working-days before I get my Macbook back ***with functioning trackpad!***

The steps we've taken during the phone call:

1. Shut down the Macbook, connect the charger and perform a SMC-reset. (The led indicator on the magsafe will turn from orange to green and back to orange if successful)
2. Boot with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> - this step was taken to check if the touchpad works in Recovery Mode, ruling out Mavericks being the issue.